# How do bool values and variables get sent between classes/forms?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble getting a method working and I am not sure I am doing it the correct way. What I want to do is to send a string from a form by a button_click into a class and process it there for errors(tryparse method) and the send a boolvalue back to then either report and error to the user or to print input in an listbox.

This is the form code I have that is supposed to send the string into the class.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Errorcheck.GetDouble(numChoice);
}
```

and then the Errorcheck class:

```
public static bool GetDouble(string numChoice, out double value, double minLimit, double maxLimit)
{
     while (!double.TryParse(numChoice, out value))
     {
          if ((value >= minLimit) && (value <= maxLimit))
          {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

How do I retrieve the bool value from the `Errorcheck` class? if it was ok or not. Am I doing the right way or is there a quicker way to go about it?

Comment: Your GetDouble method is scary. If "numChoice" is not a double value then you stay in an endless loop checking on the value. Try use "if" instead and check for minLimit and MaxLimit if TryParse is actual successful (true.) And if TryParse actually is successful in parsing the double value from numChoice, then you "return false;" since "!true" is equal to false and your while loop ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double foo;
   var myresult = Errorcheck.GetDouble(numChoice, out foo, 1, 2);

   //When myresult == true, foo contains the parsed value
}
```

`myresult` will contain the result returned by GetDouble either `true` (value could be parsed and is within limits) or `false` (value could be parsed but was out of limits or failed to parse in the first place). Also, `foo` [will contain 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) if parsing failed, otherwise the parsed value (**which, may or may not!**) be within the limits.

I do, however, have some problems with your code. First; why is your class named `Errorcheck` while, in fact, it doesn't do error-checking (what is that anyway?) but parse a value.

Second, why use the while() construct?

```
public static bool GetDouble(string numChoice, out double value, double minLimit, double maxLimit)
{
    return double.TryParse(numChoice, out value)
             && ((value >= minLimit) && (value <= maxLimit));
}
```

Third; GetDouble() doesn't actually "get" a "double". It checks if a value is parseable as a double and, if so, is within bounds. It returns a bool for Pete's sake.
**EDIT** Scratch that; I missed the `out` on the method signature. It returns a bool and also the value.

...and then some more but I might be nitpicking :P

And, last but not least, I don't see what this has to do with "how bool values and variables get sent between classes/forms"?

Take my, well intended, advice and get a good C# or general book on programming and brush up your basic skills a little. You will only benefit and soon you'll see why your code is, no flame intended, "bad" in many ways.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! This is the part that was giving me the most trubble but the class will do more then this..i hope haha :) I am a complete beginner so i was under the impression that 'while' would be the best option for this type of code but i stand corrected. :) Thanks for the help!! :))

Comment: Got the book, google and you guys and its still not easy ;) I am learning thou :) Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like that:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double parsedValue;
    if (Errorcheck.IsDoubleBetween(numChoice, out parsedValue, maxValue, minValue))
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Errorcheck code:

```
public static bool IsDoubleBetween(string numChoice, out double value, double minLimit, double maxLimit)
{
    bool result = double.TryParse(numChoice, out value) && (value >= minLimit) && (value <= maxLimit);

    return result;
}
```

As you can see, there are a few changes:

1. The name `IsDoubleBetween` explains the method logic.
2. There is a call to `IsDoubleBetween` with the right parameters.
3. There is a use of `IsDoubleBetween` return value.
4. `IsDoubleBetween` code is more readable.

In this case i would try to separate the two operations of `IsDoubleBetween` to two methods so there will be single responsibility to each - parsing and checking between value

Comment: Why not just do `return Double.TryParse`? It will save you some MSIL instructions that store then retrieve the result.

Comment: One of the problems I have with the original (and this) code is that it, "as a sideeffect" also returns the parsed value (which isn't clear from your, nor the original, methodname). And, worse, that value might be out of bounds; you need the returned bool for that.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I usually do that for debugging reasons... (you can add a breakpoint on the return line and see the exact return value instead of trying to figure out each one of the boolean values used)

Comment: @RobIII you just got me before i could update the answer and add the last line... and how can it be out of bounds? TryParse will take care of that and i return bool

Comment: @eyossi I meant the `minLimit` and `maxLimit` "bounds" ;-) +1 on the separation of concerns.

Comment: @RobIII i guess i don't understand what you mean... if it is out of the bounds the result will be false... the value will be parsed still because this methods has two responsibilities (which is bad)

Comment: @eyossi Indeed, the result will be false but the `out` parameter would still contain a value out of bounds; if you would forget to check the result (which would be easy because 2 things are 'returned') you would happily process a value that was out of bounds. The only option would be to return a "magic" value (0, NaN, -1, whatever) to indicate the value was out of bounds and then it gets really nasty and messy. That is one of the reasons giving the method two responsibilities is a bad idea.

Comment: @RobIII That is why i added that the method should be separated so it won't have two responsibilities. i agree of course :-)